# .classpath file in the Project Deliverables

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am set to deliver my ant based project and the bare minimum requirement for that i.e src folder with all source file and build.xml works fine for me with command prompt but then i see my project in eclipse and it has 2 errors

1. Description Resource    Path    Location    Type Project 'Arcusys' is missing
   required source folder: 'CustomerTest'  Arcusys     Build path  Build
   Path Problem
2. The project cannot be built until build path errors are
   resolved    Arcusys     Unknown Java Problem

these are related to .classpath as i do not have .classpath file in my current directory question. How can i avoid this error

Thank You

Comment: If the project builds with ant why do you care if there are errors in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java project in Eclipse requires a certain amount of book-keeping. Depending on the specific type of the Java project (Java, Plug-in Development, Groovy, ...) you might need more or less of this.

The same book-keeping information might not necessarily be needed to build the project - whether this is done by ANT or Maven - but have to be present nevertheless. Both ANT and Maven have their own ways to represent the same information (`build.xml` and `pom.xml`) and to some extend the synchronization between  the different forms can be automated...

A Java project in Eclipse needs the following book-keeping files:

- `.project` - the basic information about the Eclipse project, including the "type" of the project in the form of "project natures" and "builders"
- `.settings/*` - the preferences for the specific project in the form of a number of `.pref` files (almost the same as Java `.properties` files)
- `.classpath` - the build information in the form of dependencies on JRE version, other projects and special libraries (e.g. JUnit)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go into Project Properties and set the classpath under "Resource -> Linked Resource". You can also set a runtime or Launch classpath variable. It looks like you may have other resources to link as  well